# Rails Controller action: Customize key in params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails 3.1.x app and I have the following set of models:

```
class Widget
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  embeds_many :comments
end

class ShinyWidget < Widget; end
class DullWidget < Widget; end  

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :message
  embedded_in :widget
end
```

So basically I need to allow comments to be associated with different types of widgets. Using the standard resources in my routes such as:

```
resources: widgets do
  resources :comments
end
```

That exposes urls such as `GET /widgets`, `GET /widgets/:widget_id/comments`, etc. However, I'd like to expose an API for adding comments to different types of widgets. I'd like those API URL's to look something like:

```
GET /shinywidgets/:widget_id/comments
POST /shinywidgets/:widget_id/comments
```

However, I'm ok with having a ShinyWidgetsController and a DullWidgetsController, but I'd like to only create a single CommentsController. Since I haven't thought of a nice way of having a single CommentsController to handle comments for different types of widgets, I tried this:

```
resources :widgets do
  get 'comments', to: 'widgets#comments_index'
  post 'comments', to: 'widgets#comments_create'
end
```

When doing a POST to /widgets/:widget_id/comments the `params` hash stores the comment data that's being posted in a key named `widget` instead of what I was hoping for `comment`.

I know if used `resources :comments` Rails would change that key in the `params` hash to be `comment`, but can I tell Rails what to name that key given my current setup?

Currently I have to create a comment doing something like this:

```
def comments_create
  widget = Widget.find(params.delete :widget_id)
  comment = widget.comments.create(params[:widget])
end
```

I'd really like to have:

```
comment = widget.comments.create(params[:comment])
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with routes. Your form determines what `params` looks like. Please post you form.

Comment: There isn't a form, this is being exposed as JSON API.

Comment: Could you show *that* code then?

Comment: @Mischa I updated my question to show my models

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was: what does the JSON look like that gets posted to `/shinywidgets/:widget_id/comments` in order to create the comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently very wrong.

In order to make this work as it should, you should create a route like this

```
resources :widgets do
  get  'comments' => 'comments#index'
  post 'comments' => 'comments#create'
end
```

and when posting to this `CommentsController`, you pass in the comment info correctly in the `prams[:comment]`.

Your controller would have actions like this

```
def create
  widget = Widget.find(params.delete :widget_id)
  comment = widget.comments.create(params[:comment])
end
```

Comment: the problem here is the "API" that is exposed is /widgets/:widget_id/comments instead of /shinywidgets/:widget_id/comments and /dullwidgets/:widget_id/comments

Comment: You are gonna use STI for that, you can get the id for the widget on  the `:widget_id` param, and when you find it, the comment will be assigned to the correct class.

Comment: @codecraig Why would the comment model care which kind of widget it is? if they are both widgets, by associating the comment with it, it will work correctly

Comment: that's true. now say instead of requiring clients to provide the unique database ID when making a request they could provide the 'name' of a widget where the name only has to be unique to a particular type of widget. So there could be "SuperDuper" shinywidget and a "SuperDuper" dullwidget. How would I locate the correct widget when the name is only unique to the type? I guess I might have to inspect the requested URL and if I see "/shinywidgets" I find the ShinyWidget whose name is equal to the one given in the URL. is there another (or better) way?

Comment: That's a specific question for your app. With this design you need to know the type of the widget, you could do something like `widgets/:widget_type/:widget_id` for a url like `/widgets/shiny/super_duper/' or simply make different arbitrary urls to different actions. That will depend on other things like, how many widget types there are? are they dynamic? but that's all another question :)

Comment: Can I use `resources` in my routes but have it pass in `widget_name` instead of `widget_id` just to make it clear that the API wants the name?

Comment: with the resources helper I don't think so, but as I said, this is another question.Please upvote/mark as correct and post this architectural question as a new one :)